# Why is my sub-category template showing the wrong posts

Tags: categories, templates

I've got a problem with a custom category template. Used on sub-categories for a particular parent.

For some odd reason it's not showing posts store within it, but instead from a another sub-category.

I don't quite understand it, as the loop is the same as is used on my category.php page. The difference if the code before hand.

Here is the code:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>


<?php global $post; ?>
<?php
$src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), array( 5600,1000 ), false, '' );
?>
<div class="parallax" id="parallax1" style="background: url(<?php echo $src[0]; ?> ) !important; background-position: 50% 50% !important; background-repeat: no-repeat !important; background-size: cover; background-attachment: fixed !important;">
    <div class="parallax-content">
        <h1 class="page-title"><?php
                printf( __( '%s', 'adventure' ), '<span>' . single_cat_title( '', false ) . '</span>' );
        ?></h1>
        <?php
            // Display optional category description
            $category_description = category_description();
            if ( ! empty( $category_description ) )
            echo '<div class="archive-meta">' . $category_description . '</div>';
            get_template_part( 'loop', 'category' );            
        ?>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="page-wrapper">

<div id="content-container">
  <div class="page-content">
        <!-- START THE LOOP -->
        <?php $posts=query_posts($query_string . '&order=asc');
while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

        <?php echo catch_video() ?>

            <!-- Get featured image -->
                    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                    </a>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <div class="post-content">

                <div class="post-info top">
                    <span class="post-date"><?php the_date('j F, Y'); ?></span>
                    <span class="no-caps post-autor">by <?php the_author(); ?></span>
                </div>
                <h1 class="post-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
                <?php print_excerpt(500); ?>
                <a class="read-more-btn" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php _e( 'Read More &rarr;'); ?></a>
                <div class="post-info bottom">
                    <span class="post-date">In: <?php the_category(', ') ?>&nbsp;    <?php comments_number( 'no comments', 'one comment', '% comments' ); ?> </a>
</span>
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>

            </div><!-- post content -->
        </article>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <div id="blog-pagination">
        <div class="alignleft"><?php previous_posts_link('«&nbsp; Previous'); ?></div>
        <div class="alignright"><?php next_posts_link('Next &nbsp; »'); ?></div>
    </div>
  </div><!-- page content -->


</div><!-- content container -->
</div><!-- page wrapper -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Can anyone help me understand what is happening here. I thought it might be because there is some kind of pseudo loop used to get the category titles and description, but I tired resetting the query 'wp_reset_query();' without any success.

Thanks

Comment: what's inside the file `loop-category.php`? also note that you should never use `query_posts`. see [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) for changing the sort order on your category pages.

Comment: I don't have a loop-category.php never seen one in a theme before. There's a category.php, but I've not got it active at the moment, so if WP doesn't find a template with will use index.php.

Comment: Right, so it looks like query_posts is the problem as that upsets the loop. Remove that and it all works as normal. Now I just need to get my posts for that page in ASC order.

Comment: You should never under any circumstances use `query_posts`, use `WP_Query` or the `pre_get_posts` filter instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `query_posts` and add a `pre_get_posts` action to your `functions.php` file to modify sort order:

```
function wpd_category_sort_order( $query ) {
    if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_category() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpd_category_sort_order' );
```

Comment: The thing is if I do that it's going to change it for every category. I only want it on sub-categories of category 67.